# Disable Eslint failOnError causing Webpack to stop compilation with Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, eslint, vuejs3

I'm migrating an application from Vue 2 to 3. After a mess with a lot of peer depencies errors, my project finally builds up but the new version of WebPack think that EsLint error are real errors and stop the build if for example, there is variable declared but not used.

I'm aware that I can disable that behavior by setting the flag `failOnError` to `false`. But I can't figure out where I should write it. I do not have a `webpack.config.js` file it seams `Vue.JS` handle it for me so I've the following `vue.config.js` file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        _: 'lodash'
      })
    ]
  },

  publicPath: '',

  pluginOptions: {
    cordovaPath: 'src-cordova'
  },
  
  devServer: { https: false }
}
```

Is it the right place? Should I create a `webpack.config.js` file?

PS: If you need more informations, then just leave a comment :)

Comment: place an [eslint config file](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats) at the root of the project.

Comment: [Inspecting the Project's Webpack Config](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config)

Comment: This might be useful too: https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/eslint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Vue CLI 5 scaffolded project (with Webpack 5), you can disable the [`EslintWebpackPlugin` 's `failOnError`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/eslint-webpack-plugin/#failonerror) via Vue CLI's [`chainWebpack` option](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#chainwebpack).

1. In `chainWebpack(config)`, use [`config.plugin('eslint')`](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain/tree/v6#config-plugins) to get the `EslintWebpackPlugin`.
2. Chain a [`.tap(args)` call to modify the plugin's arguments](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain/tree/v6#config-plugins-modify-arguments) (`args` is an object array in this case). The first argument is the [options object for the plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/eslint-webpack-plugin/#options). Set that object's `failOnError` property to `false`:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  chainWebpack(config) {
    config.plugin('eslint')
          .tap(args => {
            args[0].failOnError = false
            return args
          })
  },
})
```